# How to Bootstrap navbar static to fixed on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to make static navbar to fixed navbar on scroll, when it reaches top of the page.

Is there a way to get it using bootstrap 3 css or javascript?

Comment: Please share your code via fiddle, so we can try on that :)

Comment: DO you want to make `static navbar` to `fixed navbar` when user scrolls down?

Comment: @anup yes, I want like that

Comment: Here take a look : 
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: For future readers using Bootstrap 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237406/animate-shrink-navbar-on-scroll-using-bootstrap-4/42250478#42250478

Answer (score 70):

If I'm not wrong, what you're trying to achieve is called Sticky navbar.

With a few lines of jQuery and the scroll event is pretty easy to achieve:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var menu = $('.menu');
    var content = $('.content');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            menu.addClass('sticky');
            content.addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('sticky');
            content.removeClass('menu-padding');
        }
    }

    $(document).scroll();

});
```

I've done a quick working sample for you, hope it helps: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yeco/4EcFf/

To make it work with **Bootstrap** you only need to add or remove "navbar-fixed-top" instead of the "sticky" class in the jsfiddle .

Comment: This worked but it needed a few tweaks for my project. It would be better if you checked for `$('.menu').hasClass('sticky');` before doing manupilations. If you experience flickering with Bootstrap this tip might help.

Comment: On bootstrap 4 it has changed to "fixed-top"

Answer (score 23):

Use the `affix` component included with Bootstrap. Start with a 'navbar-static-top' and this will change it to `fixed` when the height of your header (content above the navbar) is reached...

```
$('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height()
      }
});
```

http://bootply.com/107973

Comment: Content jumps a little when navbar became fixed. Any way to fix it?

Comment: used your example - is there a possibility to put a brand-logo in the navbar after affix was called? so the content of navbar jumping slightly to the right to make place for a logo and then the logo shrinks (from the header) into the navbar?

Answer (score 13):

I am note sure, what you are expecting. Have a look at this fiddle, this might help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/JK52L/8/

You HTML should have the class `navbar-fixed-top` or `navbar-fixed-bottom`.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 0){
        console.log(scrollTop);
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-static-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-static-top');
    }
});
```

Comment: dynamically I would like to change nav-static-top to nav-fixed-top,

Comment: my navbar after some banner content in page, when page scrolls down and navbar reached top of the page, navbar should be fixed top, vice-versa!

Comment: perfet solution.

Comment: When it reaches end of the page and while scrolling, it flickers the page. page is shacking. This is happening when you resize the window, otherwise its fine.  @moustacheman do you have solution for this??

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using Bootstrap's affix plugin:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="container-fluid">
    ...
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    ...
</nav>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height()
      }
});
```

Set `padding-top` to your `body` equal to that of your `nav`'s height so that the content overlayed by the fixed navbar is visible.

```
$('nav').on('affix.bs.affix', function (){
     $('body').css('margin-top', $('nav').height());
});

$('nav').on('affix-top.bs.affix', function (){
     $('body').css('margin-top', 0);
});
```

To get the `nav` to stick on top while scrolling add this bit of CSS.

**CSS:**

```
.affix
{
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Good ideas, but what worked better for me was `<div id='affix-placeholder' style='height:0'>&nbsp;</div>`, and set that height instead of body margin-top.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem but the solution that worked for me was:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="container-fluid">
    ...
</header>
<nav class="row">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.onscroll = function() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('header').height() ) {
        $('nav > div.navbar').removeClass('navbar-static-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
    else {
        $('nav > div.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-static-top');
    }
};
```

Where `header` was the banner tag above my navigation bar

Answer (score 3):

Set on nav

```
style="position:fixed; width:100%;"
```

Answer (score 2):

> Or you can change position of specific `div` using class name

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 0){
        //console.log(scrollTop);
        $('.header').css("position","fixed");
    } else {
         $('.header').css("position","relative");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
/**
 * Scroll management
 */
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Define the menu we are working with
    var menu = $('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-inverse');

    // Get the menus current offset
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    /**
     * scroll
     * Perform our menu mod
     */
    function scroll() {

        // Check the menus offset. 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {

            //If it is indeed beyond the offset, affix it to the top.
            $(menu).addClass('navbar-fixed-top');

        } else {

            // Otherwise, un affix it.
            $(menu).removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');

        }
    }

    // Anytime the document is scrolled act on it
    document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

```css
.navbar-wrapper{
    background:url('http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2012/10/21/20181/cad2441dd3252cf53f12154412286ba0.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

h1{
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#login-dp{
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 14px 14px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
#login-dp .help-block{
    font-size:12px    
}
#login-dp .bottom{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    clear:both;
    padding:14px;
}
#login-dp .social-buttons{
    margin:12px 0    
}
#login-dp .social-buttons a{
    width: 49%;
}
#login-dp .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn-fb{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#3b5998;
}
.btn-fb:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#496ebc 
}
.btn-tw{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#55acee;
}
.btn-tw:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#59b5fa;
}
@media(max-width:768px){
    #login-dp{
        background-color: inherit;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #login-dp .bottom{
        background-color: inherit;
        border-top:0 none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">  
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Login dropdown</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
  </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- /.navbar-wrapper -->
  
 <section>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <h1>Content</h1>
       <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi congue luctus placerat. Sed nisl sem, pellentesque at risus eget, consequat bibendum velit. Sed interdum accumsan luctus. Duis rhoncus suscipit hendrerit. Vestibulum ut lobortis diam. Donec magna est, euismod non ligula in, congue aliquet diam. Sed pellentesque erat nibh, et blandit quam auctor eget. Integer fringilla turpis ac sagittis mattis. In in metus posuere, tincidunt orci non, lobortis ipsum. Praesent porttitor orci a ligula facilisis porta. Nullam tincidunt feugiat dignissim.
       </p>
       <p>
         Pellentesque cursus suscipit massa ut molestie. Duis malesuada consequat venenatis. Vestibulum accumsan lorem sit amet vehicula tristique. Donec nec mauris quis mi imperdiet vestibulum. Praesent tempor velit at posuere posuere. Mauris tellus diam, dictum sed molestie eu, lobortis nec diam. Mauris molestie nulla vulputate, lobortis urna eget, gravida erat. Phasellus in ullamcorper lacus, eget ullamcorper odio.
       </p>
       <p>
         Quisque gravida nulla eros. Duis sit amet rhoncus felis. Etiam in malesuada nisl. Proin sit amet elit sit amet erat dapibus pretium. Duis a dignissim lacus, vitae mollis nunc. Donec ut tempor magna. Maecenas eget felis eget ipsum porttitor dapibus vitae vitae magna. Cras et felis eros. Nam dolor odio, bibendum ut ex eu, facilisis suscipit ipsum. Aliquam sit amet nunc volutpat, aliquet nunc ut, tempor augue. Pellentesque semper vestibulum lacinia. Nam lacinia erat interdum purus consequat elementum. Phasellus volutpat sed libero id molestie. Quisque nec iaculis nisl, vitae accumsan justo. Suspendisse sollicitudin metus in libero cursus tempor in eget enim.
       </p>
       <p>
         Suspendisse nibh lacus, consequat et tincidunt eget, interdum mollis velit. Etiam lobortis ac tellus et pretium. Nunc a tincidunt nulla. Cras vel nulla in neque accumsan fermentum. Etiam ac erat leo. Vestibulum aliquam dignissim lectus, tincidunt consequat augue malesuada at. Pellentesque semper viverra elit quis vestibulum. Aliquam rutrum justo dignissim ligula fringilla, ac viverra metus efficitur.
       </p>
       <p>
         Mauris quis nisi convallis, rhoncus odio non, sodales urna. Donec ac ante at nisi pulvinar eleifend. Duis vel suscipit est. Nullam quis aliquet eros. Maecenas tincidunt augue condimentum nisi pharetra, in molestie libero condimentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi quis elit id nunc faucibus egestas. Sed non vehicula ligula, quis viverra urna. Nunc nec eleifend elit. Sed aliquam nibh non turpis congue, a condimentum mauris dictum. Vivamus laoreet nulla vel elit consequat, non convallis nibh dapibus. Mauris maximus nibh maximus, sollicitudin odio nec, semper nunc. Nunc consequat convallis lobortis. Aliquam pulvinar porttitor lorem. Donec luctus, libero a interdum posuere, est tellus tincidunt risus, a fermentum lacus odio at metus. Donec maximus ante massa, imperdiet consequat magna lobortis sed.
       </p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

hey all everyone is over thinking this all you need to do is wrap the nav in a  like below:

csscode:

```
#navwrap {  
    height: 100px;   (change dependant on hight of nav)
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navwrap">
    nav code inside
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

/**
 * Scroll management
 */
$(document).ready(function () {

```
// Define the menu we are working with
var menu = $('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-inverse');

// Get the menus current offset
var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

/**
 * scroll
 * Perform our menu mod
 */
function scroll() {

    // Check the menus offset. 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {

        //If it is indeed beyond the offset, affix it to the top.
        $(menu).addClass('navbar-fixed-top');

    } else {

        // Otherwise, un affix it.
        $(menu).removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');

    }
}

// Anytime the document is scrolled act on it
document.onscroll = scroll;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

set max-height as you need:

```
.navbar-fixed-top 
.navbar-collapse, 
.navbar-fixed-bottom 
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation using the Affix Bootstrap plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

It includes some extra affix problems solved (see below).

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="top_navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
... (typical Bootstrap top navbar)
  </div>
</div>

...
...
...

<div id="parent-navbar-main" >
  <div id="navbar-main">
... (here is your nav panel to get sticky on scroll)
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function set_sticky_panel()  {

  var affixElement = $('#navbar-main');

  var navbarElementHeight = $('#top_navbar').height();

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683303/bootstrap-3-0-affix-with-list-changes-width
  var width = affixElement.parent().width();
  affixElement.width(width);

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410765/get-full-height-of-element
  var affixElementHeight = $('#navbar-main').outerHeight(true);

// https://finiteheap.com/webdev/2014/12/26/bootstrap-affix-flickering.html  
  affixElement.parent().height(affixElementHeight);

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797241/resetting-changing-the-offset-of-bootstrap-affix
  $(window).off('.affix')
  affixElement.removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom')


  affixElement.affix({
    offset: {
    // Distance of between element and top page
      top: function () {
      // how much scrolling is done until sticking the panel
        return (this.top = affixElement.offset().top - parseInt(navbarElementHeight,10))
      }
    }
  });

  // The replacement for the css-file.
  affixElement.on('affix.bs.affix', function (){
  // the absolute position where the sticked panel is to be placed when the fixing event fires (e.g. the panel reached the top of the page).
    affixElement.css('top', navbarElementHeight + 'px');
    affixElement.css('z-index', 10);
  });

}

$(document).on('ready', set_sticky_panel);

$(window).resize(set_sticky_panel);
```

**CSS:**

> No css is required.

If to compare with the standart implementation my code additionaly solves these problems:

1. The width of the sticky panel does not break at the fixing event anymore.
2. The need in the CSS-file usage is eliminated.
3. Reformatting the sticky panel size on the window change size event (responsiveness) is done now.
4. No more affix flittering / jumping at the fixing event.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the code like this:

```
<div class="scroll"> 
<div class="menu">home | services | contact</div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.scroll {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
.menu {
  position:absolute;
  background:#428bca;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:30px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
.menu-padding {
  // no  style here anymore 
}
```

Then the annoying scroll is gone.

The compleet code and fiddle is not originally made by me, I got it from an earlier answer in this topic. The change in the code is made by me

Fabian #Web-Stars

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EcFf/1183/)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit older, it's solved by CSS and latest bootstrap natively.

If you add the class `sticky-top` to your navbar it will behave just like the javascript/jquery in the best current answer but without any javascript.
Browser support is quite decent but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, which is the latest version as writing this answer, the assingments have changed a bit. Here is an example of a navbar fixed on top:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>Navbar</h1></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed to top**

Make bootstrap navbar fixed on scroll

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
          ...
     </div> 
</nav>
```