# bootstrap navbar container when scroll down navbar fixed top container fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, containers, navbar, affix

I wanna ask some help from you guys with regards of bootstrap navbar container when it scrolls down the navbar fixed at the top and the same time container fluid

[image: what i mean]

I provide you also codepen link so you play around [Codepen](https://codepen.io/surqc/pen/zdoEzd) `div`

Comment: yes it's matter, how they will help you if they don't understand your questions?

Comment: original op's question is using bad english apparently some people could decipher it and  apparently the question is just as same as  [How to Bootstrap navbar static to fixed on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301316/how-to-bootstrap-navbar-static-to-fixed-on-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

If I understand your question, you want to affix the navbar to the top after the user begins to scroll. Well, here is my implementation of of this... I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21301875 and modified it for this scenario as well as documented the code.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/phatison/pen/dVewqd)

```
/**
 * Scroll management
 */
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Define the menu we are working with
    var menu = $('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-inverse');

    // Get the menus current offset
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    /**
     * scroll
     * Perform our menu mod
     */
    function scroll() {

        // Check the menus offset. 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {

            //If it is indeed beyond the offset, affix it to the top.
            $(menu).addClass('navbar-fixed-top');

        } else {

            // Otherwise, un affix it.
            $(menu).removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');

        }
    }

    // Anytime the document is scrolled act on it
    document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

Comment: thank you sir one more thing can i use css transition in the navbar?

Answer (score -3):

add container-fluid in line 3

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

add navbar fixed top in line 5

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLVaEm)

see the documentation; your answer is covered there.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: `Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.` idk why its downvoted the original op's question itself is using confusing english, of course I will not post this as and answer if OP ask using understandable english like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301316/how-to-bootstrap-navbar-static-to-fixed-on-scroll/21301875).


you could check byurself the date I answer, the date the question edited and its history, and the accepted answer date.