# navbar isn't sticky top when scroll page

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

i have a problem with navbar.
This is my code:

```
 <nav id="strumenti" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light sticky">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="C:\Users\Fabry\Desktop\scuola\html\Immagini\UltrasAvellino\clan.ico" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Ultras Avellino 
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills" id="pills-tab" role=tablist>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">War</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Regole</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">La nostra storia</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Contattaci</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar has class sticky, so it should stay at top, but when i scroll about middle of page, it disappears.
i tried to add position:fixed in css and it remains at top, but is below other elements.
Pleas help me.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/21301316/1531971 But you might need to tell us why the many other QA found doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fixed-top instance of sticky

```
<nav id="strumenti" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Check: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement